# JUNG: unpicked vertex label color

Tags: colors, label, renderer, jung, vertex

I can make **picked** vertex labels red using vertexLabelRenderer declared like this:

```
DefaultVertexLabelRenderer vertexLabelRenderer=new DefaultVertexLabelRenderer(Color.RED);
```

How do I change color of **unpicked** vertex labels. Constructor (see below) only allows defining **unpicked** vertex labels. Also method setForeground() does not affect the font color.

Here is the JUNG 2.0.1 API document:
http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/apidocs/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/renderers/DefaultVertexLabelRenderer.html

Comment: I created a new class MyDefaultVertexLaberRenderer with an additional field "protected Color unpickedVertexLabelColor = Color.black;". With trivial modification to DefaultVertexLabelRenderer.java this solves the problem. Do tell me if there is a solution that does not involve tampering the JUNG library.

Comment: Your solution does not involve tampering with JUNG, you're just providing your own class.  JUNG can't possibly provide all possible options in the classes that it provides; it seems like writing your own class (which, as you said, is a trivial modification of an existing class) is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone still scratching their head here's two simple classes that can change an unpicked vertex/edge label color.

```java
public class MyDefaultVertexLaberRenderer extends DefaultVertexLabelRenderer
{
    protected Color unpickedVertexLabelColor = Color.BLACK;

    public MyDefaultVertexLaberRenderer(Color unpickedVertexLabelColor, Color pickedVertexLabelColor)
    {
        super(pickedVertexLabelColor);
        this.unpickedVertexLabelColor = unpickedVertexLabelColor;
    }

    public <V> Component getVertexLabelRendererComponent(JComponent vv, Object value, Font font, boolean isSelected, V vertex)
    {
        super.setForeground(unpickedVertexLabelColor);
        if (isSelected) setForeground(pickedVertexLabelColor);
        super.setBackground(vv.getBackground());
        if (font != null)
        {
            setFont(font);
        }
        else
        {
            setFont(vv.getFont());
        }
        setIcon(null);
        setBorder(noFocusBorder);
        setValue(value);
        return this;
    }
}

public class MyDefaultEdgeLaberRenderer extends DefaultEdgeLabelRenderer
{
    protected Color unpickedEdgeLabelColor = Color.BLACK;

    public MyDefaultEdgeLaberRenderer(Color unpickedEdgeLabelColor, Color pickedEdgeLabelColor)
    {
        super(pickedEdgeLabelColor);
        this.unpickedEdgeLabelColor = unpickedEdgeLabelColor;
    }

    public <E> Component getEdgeLabelRendererComponent(JComponent vv, Object value, Font font, boolean isSelected, E edge)
    {
        super.setForeground(unpickedEdgeLabelColor);
        if (isSelected) setForeground(pickedEdgeLabelColor);
        super.setBackground(vv.getBackground());

        if (font != null)
        {
            setFont(font);
        }
        else
        {
            setFont(vv.getFont());
        }
        setIcon(null);
        setBorder(noFocusBorder);
        setValue(value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, how do you use that piece of code, though?

Comment: All you have to do is copy each class into a separate java source file and then to use instantiations of them you would say: 

vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelRenderer(new MyDefaultVertexLaberRenderer(Color.RED, Color.BLUE));

vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelRenderer(new MyDefaultEdgeLaberRenderer(Color.RED, Color.BLUE));

Where vv is your VisualizationViewer instance, red is the unpicked color and blue is the picked color. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to set the color of unpicked vertex labels (to red):

```
vv.setForegroundColor(Color.red);
```

The vertex (and edge) labels use a JLabel, and they grab the foreground color from the visualization viewer.